# Delete cart products using observer in magento

Tags: magento

I want to delete cart product using observer.

I am able to get all products of current cart but after trying lots of times I can't delete products from cart using observer.
Even also tried to delete products using query but again product was not deleted.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Check_Price>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Check_Price>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <checkprice>
                <class>Observerexample_Model</class>
            </checkprice>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_before>
                <observers>
                    <check_price_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Check_Price_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>example</method>
                    </check_price_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_before> 
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

I have used this code in observer:-

```
 $event = $observer->getEvent();
         $order = $event->getOrder();
         $items = $order->getQuote()->getAllItems();        
         foreach ($items as $item) {
           if($item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice()==0){

             ??
           }          
         }
```

I have everything like itemID,quoteID
How to delete products from cart.

Answer (score 0):

There Lot of issue in config.xml

**1.Model prefix issue:**
1st of all model prefix class is not right. It Should be

```
<models>
            <checkprice>
                <class>Check_Price_Model_Model</class>
            </checkprice>
        </models>
```

from

```
<models>
    <checkprice>
        <class>Observerexample_Model</class>
    </checkprice>
</models>
```

**Issue2:** `sales_order_place_before` event is called for all case of order place.It called whenever `$orderObject` call it function: `place()` function. you see at class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`.
It will be better idea to use event `checkout_submit_all_after`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
I want to delete zero price product from cart using observer.
but when I am using "checkout_submit_all_after" event my observer will occur after all processes like checkout, payment and place order.
but i want to call by observer just after clicking on checkout button or just after clicking place order button.

so please tell me what i do.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a cart item by the item's id. Here's how to remove an item with id = 1:

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->removeItem(1);
```

Here's how to remove all items:

```
$quote = $cart->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem){
   $cart->removeItem($cartItem->getId());
}
```